# Sending simple HTTP Post Request on ESP8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I need to send simple HTTP POST Request using ESP8266. It's containing data in "form-data".

It should look like this:

```
POST http://testserver.com
{
  "auth_key":"key",
  "data":[
    {
      "key":"temperature",
      "value":31.2
    },
    {
      "key":"humidity",
      "value":50
    }
  ]
}
```

For the testing I was using Chrome application - Postman. And the HTTP Request code which I send was looking like this (it was automatically generated):

```
POST /api/mes HTTP/1.1
Host: testserver.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 9b910ed2-afdc-2a11-4963-2f85626cfa4e
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="auth_key"

79bde0ff1efeaee90b1e432c08d324ecfdb532ac42406d7a9a87dd911e95f87e
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

[{"key":"humidity", "value":55}]
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

And through Postman everything was okay. So then I sent it through ESP8266:

```
client.setNoDelay(true);
client.println("POST /api/mes HTTP/1.1");
client.println("Host: testserver.com");
client.println("Cache-Control: no-cache");
client.println("Postman-Token: 9b910ed2-afdc-2a11-4963-2f85626cfa4e");
client.println("Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
client.println("");
client.println("------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
client.println("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"auth_key\"");
client.println("");
client.println("79bde0ff1efeaee90b1e432c08d324ecfdb532ac42406d7a9a87dd911e95f87e");
client.println("------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
client.println("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"data\"");
client.println("");
client.println("[{\"key\":\"humidity\", \"value\":55}]");
client.println("------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--");
```

But unfortunately server is returning that the request is not correct. What can cause the problem? I'm struggling with it but I don't have any more ideas.

Comment: Is `auth_key` fixed? If not, do you have the same key on a second request with Postman after closing the browser? Maybe try to combine the headers in one string, and then send the whole string. Are you sure there was no Content-Length header? Is Postman-Token needed? If yes, does it change each request?

Comment: I don't need this postman token, it's added with this Postman application (I was using it only for testing). But even commenting or making it one string doesn't help. It seems that there is no data sent. 
I was using it for test: http://requestb.in - and for Postman chrome application there is data sent and for ESP there isnt

Comment: Well, you said that the server is returning a message, so some data would have to be sent then?

Comment: http://i68.tinypic.com/11mc782.jpg - good http request through Postman
http://i64.tinypic.com/2h4gkfk.jpg - bad http request through ESP

Comment: Maybe the message is ok but the white space is wrong.  You might just be missing a `\r\n` somewhere.  Paste the postman message into a program where you can see the formatting, or try inserting the `\r\n`s manually into your message and using `client.print` to help figure it out.